# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a PostgreSQL query as below which is running fine . I am calling it from a shell script as below

```
Result=$(psql -U username -d database -t -c 
$'SELECT round(sum(i.total), 2) AS "ROUND(sum(i.total), 2)" 
  FROM invoice i 
  WHERE i.create_datetime = '2019-03-01 00:00:00-06' 
  AND i.is_review = '1' AND i.user_id != 60;')
```

now I want the value which I have hard coded as `i.create_datetime = '2019-03-01 00:00:00-06'` to replace it with a variable date value.

I have tried two ways

way 1:

```
Result=$(psql -U username -d database -t -c 
$'WITH var(reviewMonth) as (values(\'$reviewMonth\')) 
SELECT round(sum(i.total),2) AS "ROUND(sum(i.total),2)" 
FROM var,invoice i 
WHERE i.create_datetime = var.reviewMonth::timestamp 
AND i.is_review = \'1\' AND i.user_id != 60;')
```

and

way 2:

```
Result=$(psql -U username -d database -t -c 
$'SELECT round(sum(i.total),2) AS "ROUND(sum(i.total),2)" 
FROM invoice i 
WHERE i.create_datetime = \'$reviewMonth\' 
AND i.is_review = \'1\' AND i.user_id != 60;')
```

But both way it's throwing error

way 1 throwing error as :

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone = text

way 2 throwing error as :

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "$reviewMonth"

Please suggest what should be my approach.

Comment: Is it postgresql or mysql?

Comment: @nacho It is postgresql

Comment: So don't tag it as mysql

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the psql variables.  Here's an example:

```
# Put the query in a file, with the variable TSTAMP:

> echo "SELECT :'TSTAMP'::timestamp with time zone;" > query.sql
> export TSTAMP='2019-03-01 00:00:00-06'
> RESULT=$(psql -U postgres -t --variable=TSTAMP="$TSTAMP" -f query.sql )
> echo $RESULT
2019-03-01 06:00:00+00
```

Note how we format the string literal substitution in the query: :'TSTAMP'

You could also do the substitution yourself.  Here's an example using a heredoc:

```
> export TSTAMP='2019-03-01 00:00:01-06'
> RESULT=$(psql -U postgres -t << EOF
SELECT '$TSTAMP'::timestamp with time zone;
EOF
)
> echo $RESULT
2019-03-01 06:00:01+00
```

In this case, we aren't using psql's variable substitution, so we have to quote the variable like '$TSTAMP' .  Using a heredoc makes the quoting much simpler than using -c because you aren't trying to quote the whole command.

EDIT: more examples because it appears this wasn't clear enough.  TSTAMP does not have to be hard coded, it's just a bash variable than can be set like any other bash variable.

```
> TSTAMP=$(date -d 'now' +'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
> RESULT=$(psql -U postgres -t << EOF
SELECT '$TSTAMP'::timestamp with time zone;
EOF
)
> echo $RESULT
2019-06-01 00:00:00+00
```

However, if you're really just looking for the start of the month, there's no need for shell variables at all

```
> RESULT=$(psql -U postgres -t << EOF
SELECT date_trunc('month', now());
EOF
)
> echo $RESULT
2019-06-01 00:00:00+00
```

Comment: I don't think this way it will helpful for me.
I am getting reviewMonth as 
reviewMonth=$(date -d 'now' +'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')
now this reviewMonth value i want to use as 
i.create_datetime = reviewMonth value

Comment: This method should work fine for you.  Your second method above is failing due to quoting issues.  I'm showing you how to get around those.

Comment: You are hard coding the value while doing export TSTAMP. In my case it can't be hard coded as '2019-03-01 00:00:01-06' instead this value comes from 
reviewMonth=$(date -d 'now' +'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')

And more over, think like a scenario where I have a postgresql query1 which is providing 100 rows with different Ids. Now for all different Ids I have to run query 2 using a while read Id; do query 2. In query 2 now how to use the Id dynamically which has to read dynamically value from variable Id

Comment: For one, this technique would work in both cases.  The export doesn't have to be hard coded, it can be set just like any other bash variable.  Secondly, for both the cases you mention, it would most likely be better to do all of the work in postgres and not involve shell variables at all.

Comment: @abhisek I added a couple more examples.

Comment: I found a simple solution which worked. 
Earlier while calling from my scripts I was calling like below 
Result=$(psql -U username -d database -t -c $' <PostGreSQL Query> ' where it was not able to read \'$reviewMonth\'
Now what I have changed is 
Result=$(psql -U username -d database -t --command="<PostGreSQL Query>"
where it is able to read now my variable value with '$reviewMonth'